# Microsoft OneNote Xamarin.Forms Integration

Tags: xamarin.forms

Okay, first question: Is it remotely or even hypothetically possible to integrate Microsoft OneNote into Xamarin.Forms cross-platform apps.

Second question: If not OneNote, is there any kind of online collaboration tool I might be able to use?  Like, drawing, taking notes, annotations... that kind of stuff?

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer!

Comment: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/onenote

Comment: Thanks!  You wouldn't happen to know of anything simpler, would you?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate Microsoft OneNote into Xamarin.Forms, you can follow the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/integrate-with-onenote) to achieve it.
Meanwhile, the online version of Microsoft OneNote allows you to do the same function with notes,which means more than one person can be editing the same document at the same time.

For more details, you can check: https://www.lifewire.com/tips-for-sharing-and-collaborating-onenote-2512136

Besides OneNote, there are many online collaboration tool you can choose to use, e.g. `Evernote`、`Boostnote`、`Quip`、  `Simplenote`、 `Zoho Notebook` etc .

For more details, you can check:

https://zapier.com/blog/best-note-taking-apps/

https://mashable.com/video/plymouth-church-secret-basement/

Comment: @Nathan M Have you got the solution?

Comment: We're not going that route, atm